# Style even and odd Tumblr posts

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I had an idea to do a Tumblr theme where the posts are displayed differently depending on if they're even or odd. I know how to do this just straight HTML, however, I'm new to Tumblr coding. This would be what I mean:

[image: Mockup of what I'm looking to accomplish]

Any thoughts? Is this something that can be done within Tumblr's code? I know how to insert the `{Block: Post}` stuff, but I'm unsure how to make Tumblr split the posts as even or odd...

Comment: I have no idea about coding a Tumblr theme, but assuming you have basic CSS access you can achieve it with the [`:nth-child`](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html) selector. There's no need for any JS code.

Answer (score 1):

As @Rory McCrossan says, nth-child is a good way to achieve that.

```
tr {
  background: red;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: blue;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q710v9h4/

You can do nth-child(odd) or nth-child(even).
Take a look here as well: http://nthmaster.com/

Answer (score 1):

Tumblr has blocks specifically for odd and even posts. You can easily add relevant classes to your posts depending on if it is odd or even. For example:

```
<div class="post {block:Odd}odd{/block:Odd}{block:Even}even{/block:Even}">
    ...
</div>
```

You can also use these odd and even blocks to wrap around odd and even specific CSS.